# grunt-usemin and multiple path on index.html

Tags: grunt-usemin

First of all, sorry for my english and sorry to be new with grunt.

Now, my question ;-)

I have 2 directories for my Javascript files (/components and /src/main/javascript) included on the index.html which is on /src/main/html. Imagine my gruntfile on the / directory.

I would like to find the simpliest way to have an only .js for all my javascript files on the /target/gui/javascript directory.

But before that, I'm ok to have one file by javascript sources directories. But, I have a problem when I do the following comment on the index.html.

```
<!-- build:js(components/angular) javascript/components.js -->
    <script src="../../../components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js(src/main/javascript) javascript/app.js -->
    <script src="../javascript/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/lists/services/lists.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/lists/controllers/listsctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/lists/controllers/listctrl.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

My problem is that **my components.js is empty**. I can see a strange thing when I launch my grunt build :

```
    Found a block:
    <!-- build:js(components/angular) javascript/components.js -->
    <script src="../../../components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    Updating config with the following assets:
    - ../components/angular/angular.js
```

Updating with ../components/angular/angular.js ? Not components/angular/angular.js ?
I don't understand.
I did the same thing with my CSS files, and it does what I want :

```
    <!-- build:css(components/bootstrap/css) css/components.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(src/main/css) css/app.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/shoppinglist.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

I can see

```
Found a block:
    <!-- build:css(components/bootstrap/css) css/components.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
Updating config with the following assets:
    - components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
    - components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
```

So, for the CSS, grunt understand the path I want ?

What I have on my Gruntfile ?

```
    (...)
     dest: {
        buildRoot : 'target',
        guiRoot   : 'target/gui',
        html: {
           index:    'target/gui/index.html',
           partials: 'target/gui/partials'
        },
        res:        'target/gui/assets'
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= dest.html.index %>'
    },

    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= dest.html.index %>'],
      options: {
        dirs: ['<%= dest.guiRoot %>']
      }
    }
    (...)
```

I use grunt build with :

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');


    grunt.registerTask('build',   ['clean', 'copy:html', 'copy:res', 'copy:server', 'copy:heroku', 'useminPrepare', 'concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'usemin']);
```

Someone can help me ?

Best regards,

Manu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usemin's "alternate search path" is used as an origin directory to search for paths referenced in your index.html.

In your configuration, you'll have to *cancel* the three `..` in your paths in order to find the `component` directory (located in the root dir).

This config will do the trick:

```
<!-- build:js(aFakeDir/anotherFakeDir/yetAnotherFakeDir) javascript/components.js -->
    <script src="../../../components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Note that you don't have to specify real directory names.